# Array of only strings or only numbers

Tags: typescript

I can't seem to figure out how to work with an array that will be made of only strings or only numbers, basically something with type `string[] | number[]`. On such an array I can't seem to call `.push()` on it because the type for the arguments to `.push()` will be `never`.

**My use case is this:**

I have an interface like this

```
export interface Response {
  numbers: Array<number>;
  strings: Array<string>;
}

export type ResponseKey = keyof Response;
```

Then later if I index into a Response object

```
const response: Response = { numbers: [], strings: [] };
let key: ResponseKey;
// dynamicaly assign the key somehow ...
const value = response[key];
```

Now the type for `value` is `string[] | number[]`.

Comment: What value do you want to push to it? You want to write `value.push(something)`, what type of thing is `something` and where does its value come from? Please show a complete [mcve].

Comment: Unfortunately the type and value of `something` doesn't matter because arguments to `.push()` are inferred to be `never` by TypeScript so it always throws error no matter what. I could do `value.push(2)` and it would still give the error.

Comment: They matter for how you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript infers every item type to `string & number` which gives `never` because these types have nothing in common.

You could split your code into two `if` statements to narrow the `key` to its actual type:

```
export interface Response {
    numbers: Array<number>;
    strings: Array<string>;
}

type ResponseKey = keyof Response;


const response: Response = { numbers: [], strings: [] };
declare let key: ResponseKey;
// dynamicaly assign the key somehow ...


if (key === 'numbers') {
    const value = response[key]; // number[]
    value.push(2);
}

if (key === 'strings') {
    const value = response[key]; // string[]
    value.push('test');
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgJWAGdIki8BvAKDlriQFcBbAIzSIC44BBKKTAJ4AeRqzQA+ANw06RGFGQBzTjz6ChchUkVSqAXypUYAsHkIkIZYAGlgAuAF44AazsR0BYqXLTD2S3JwUF4BwFzm3nhOFPTMbFAqANoAugA0cJpKSclwetIAJsDYADaYwXDFwPCuAuEhVrYC0gD0zXD5AkiYTAjYmMX2mERECIpIcDAAFng1GRBMwJMQAO5wAHQbhlQIHgAUsw6HcADkovFExwCUcNR0cP5k8ABu-QxRQfXkiTXJ0ncvxTeazADCIk12ACZLtIDNs9gcjsdMtoLtdbnQHoEAW9HB8LFZvnZfjJaNjgMDQeDjqg5FcYUA)